# F# generate a sequence/array of dates

Tags: f#

In F# I can easily do

```
let a = [1 .. 10];;
```

Then why can't I do

```
let a = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2012")
let b = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020")


let dateList = [a .. b]
```

It gives an error `Type constraint mismatch. The type DateTime is not compatible with type TimeSpan`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems - firstly you need to specify the interval you want to use between elements of the list. This would be a `TimeSpan`, however it does not have a static `Zero` member.

This constraint is required by the [skip range operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353647) which requires the 'step' type to have static `(+)` and `Zero` members

You can define your own structure which supports the required operations however:

```
type TimeSpanW = { span : TimeSpan } with
  static member (+) (d:DateTime, wrapper) = d + wrapper.span
  static member Zero = { span = new TimeSpan(0L) }
```

You can then do:

```
let ts = new TimeSpan(...)
let dateList = [a .. {span = ts} .. b]
```

**Edit:** Here's an alternative syntax using discriminated unions that you may prefer:

```
type Span = Span of TimeSpan with
  static member (+) (d:DateTime, Span wrapper) = d + wrapper
  static member Zero = Span(new TimeSpan(0L))

let ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)
let dateList = [a .. Span(ts) .. b]
```

Comment: Works beautifully... Is there a link which explains what's going on? Why is Zero required? Also that (+) operator.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - This is required by the "skip range" operator - I've updated the answer with a link.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - what is actually going on - the step has to start at 0 and then increase - if you look at the signature, the step doesn't have to have the same type as the endpoints.

Comment: I've added an alternative method that's very similar and I personally prefer. Hope you don't mind @Lee.

Comment: @yamen I know it's an old question but the skip range operator link is broken

Answer (score 13):

Here's a funky way of generating a list of dates. Note I'm taking no credit for this whatsoever as I got it from someone else.

```
open System
let a = new DateTime(2013,12,1)
let b = new DateTime(2013,12,5)
Seq.unfold (fun d -> if d < b then Some(d, d.AddDays(1.0)) else None) a
 |> Seq.toList;;
```

It returns:

> val it : DateTime list =   [01/12/2013 00:00:00; 02/12/2013 00:00:00;
>   03/12/2013 00:00:00;    04/12/2013 00:00:00]