# F# Skip Range Operator

Tags: f#

I'm trying to generate lists of dates (time periods) in F# and I found my answer at ([F# generate a sequence/array of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176471/f-generate-a-sequence-array-of-dates)) and it works perfectly.

However I cannot wrap my ahead around the definition of the (+) static member.

static member (+) (d:DateTime, **Span wrapper**) = ...

Particularly the Span wrapper portion.  I even re-wrote is as:

static member (+) (d:DateTime, **wrapper:Span**) = ...

and even though it compiles (fsi) it does not work.

Only when I rewrote it to match the original syntax it does work as expected.

I looked at the MSDN docs as well as some of the F# books I have but I cannot find anything that explains that particular syntax for the (+) operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the context, here is original example:

```
type Span = 
  | Span of TimeSpan
  static member (+) (d:DateTime, Span wrapper) = d + wrapper
  static member Zero = Span(new TimeSpan(0L))
```

In `(+)`, the author uses pattern matching directly on the argument. It means that wrapper has type of `TimeSpan`, and `d + wrapper` is an operation between `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`

The example looks clearer in the following verbose form:

```
static member (+) (d:DateTime, span: Span) = 
    match span with
    | Span wrapper ->
         d + wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you both, it now makes sense.  I wish i could accept both answers.  They also explain that when I used the variation, it did not work because the function kept calling itself recursively and I never waited long enough for the stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite subtle syntactic trick that you can use with type definitions of the following form:

```
type MyNumber = MyNumber of int
```

This defines a *type* `MyNumber` which is an integer wrapped using a *constructor* that is also named `MyNumber`. So, we are defining a type and a constructor of the same name. We could use different names:

```
type MyNumberType = MyNumberCtor of int
```

The following syntax is used for pattern matching when you are extracting the value. Here, we are using the constructor:

```
let getNumber (MyNumber n) = n
let getNumber (MyNumberCtor n) = n
```

The following syntax is type annotation (which uses the type name):

```
let doNothing (n:MyNumber) = 1
let getNumber (n:MyNumberType) = 1
```

Here, we cannot do much with `n`, because it is the wrapped value - so we'd have to use pattern matching to extract it. As you can see in the answer from @pad, the other way to write the pattern matching is to use the `match` construct. In any case, there is nothing special related to the operators and types - it is just a naming trick that people sometimes use when defining wrappers.